# How to prevent conflicting events (I think) in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-propagation, react-beautiful-dnd

I'm using `react-beautiful-dnd`:

```
<DragDropContext>
  <Droppable>
    {(provided, snapshot) => (
      <div>
       <Draggable><Item with Slider></Draggable>
       <Draggable><Item with Slider></Draggable>
       <Draggable><Item with Slider></Draggable>
       <Draggable><Item with Slider></Draggable>
       etc
      </div>
    )}
  </Droppable>
</DragDropContext>
```

My understanding is that `Draggable` will have some variety of event listeners to allow it to detect when it is clicked/clicked and dragged/etc.

The `Slider` component that I'm using will also have similar events (since I assume it provides similar event listeners to `Draggable`).

How can I either:

1. Get `react-beautiful-dnd` to ignore events emitted from certain targets

or

2. Stop event propagation so that `react-beautiful-dnd` doesn't receive an event?

The screenshot below shows two sliders - (1) a React component (`material-ui`) and (2) an `<input type="range" />` component. The normal range works fine (doesn't trigger drag and drop) while the Slider does not.

Comment: if the slider is not supporting `stopPropagation` maybe you can wrap it with your own component that register to those events and just call `stopPropagation`?

Comment: Can I assume that an event handler of a child element will be called before an event handler of the parent?

Answer (score 1):

See this:[code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vertical-list-dgy2q?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&file=/index.js:2506-2553)

The key to accomplish this is to ***only*** add the spread `{...provided.dragHandleProps}` to the inner div and make sure that `{...provided.dragHandleProps}` is **NOT** on container parent which is usually the div which is the direct child of the `<Draggable>`

```
<Droppable droppableId="featureWidgets">
    {(provided: any) => (
        <div {...provided.droppableProps} ref={provided.innerRef}>
            <FeaturesListView>
            {featureWidgets.map(({id, type}, index) => {
                return (<Draggable key={id} draggableId={id} index={index}>
                            {(provided) => (
                                <div
                                    ref={provided.innerRef} {...provided.draggableProps} ///* NO NO not here  {...provided.dragHandleProps} */
                                    <div {...provided.dragHandleProps}>drag grip handle</div>
                                    <WidgetRow>
                                        <Slider/>
                                    </WidgetRow>
                                </div>
                            )}
                        </Draggable>);
                })}
            {provided.placeholder}
            </FeaturesListView>
        </div>
    )}
</Droppable>
```